# Show element on mouseover hide on mouseleave

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am having trouble with this feature. I want #login to appear after I mouseover #pink and to remain visible when I am hovering over #login but disappear when I hover over #green, #yellow, #purple or outside my #buttons container.

My problem is that when I hover over #green, #yellow, and #purple; #login still remains visible which don't want.

```
<div id="buttons">
  <div id="one"></div>
  <div id="two"></div>
  <div id="three"></div>
  <div id="four"></div>
    <div id="login"></div>
</div>

<script>
  $('#four').mouseover(function () {
    $('#login').show();
  });

  $('#buttons').mouseleave(function () {
    $('#login').hide();
  });
</script>
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/solxs9/j245gz3q/)

Comment: Your fiddle is working dude, i have checked adding jquery in your fiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that only with CSS just by adding these lines:

```
#login:hover,
#four:hover ~ #login { display:block }
```

---

```css
#buttons {
    width: 160px;
    background: blue;
}
#one {
    float: left;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    background: green;
}
#two {
    float: left;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    background: yellow;
}
#three {
    float: left;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    background: purple;
}
#four {
    float: left;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    background: pink;
}
#login {
    height: 100px;
    background: orange;
    display: none;
}
#login:hover,
#four:hover ~ #login { display:block }
```

```html
<div id="buttons">
    <div id="one"></div>
    <div id="two"></div>
    <div id="three"></div>
    <div id="four"></div>
    <div id="login"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow I can't believe that slipped past me. *sigh* long day. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

use structure like this :

```
<div id="buttons">
  <div id="one"></div>
  <div id="two"></div>
  <div id="three"></div>
  <div id="four">
      <div id="login"></div>
  </div>        
</div>
```

then you can achieve your function like this :

```
$('#four').mouseover(function () {
    $('#login').show();
}).mouseleave(function () {
    $('#login').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

see updated code on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j245gz3q/5/)

```
$('#four,#login').mouseover(function () {
    $('#login').show();
}).mouseleave(function(){
   $('#login').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you are needed:
[`Fiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/j245gz3q/4/)

```
<div id="buttons">
    <div id="one"></div>
    <div id="two"></div>
    <div id="three"></div>
    <div id="four" class="toggle"></div>
    <div id="login" class="toggle"></div>
</div>


$('.toggle').mouseover(function () {
    $('#login').show();
});

$('.toggle').mouseleave(function () {
    $('#login').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this too: **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/j245gz3q/6/)**

```
$('#one,#two,#three').mouseover(function () {
    $('#login').hide();

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a timer like

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  var $target = $('#login');
  $('#four').hover(function() {
    clearTimeout($target.data('hoverTimer'));
    $target.stop(true, true).slideDown(500);
  }, function() {
    var timer = setTimeout(function() {
      $target.stop(true, true).slideUp();
    }, 200);
    $target.data('hoverTimer', timer);
  });

  $target.hover(function() {
    clearTimeout($(this).data('hoverTimer'));
  }, function() {
    $(this).stop(true, true).slideUp();
  });
});
```

```css
#buttons {
  width: 160px;
  background: blue;
}
#one {
  float: left;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background: green;
}
#two {
  float: left;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background: yellow;
}
#three {
  float: left;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background: purple;
}
#four {
  float: left;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background: pink;
}
#login {
  height: 100px;
  background: orange;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="buttons">
  <div id="one"></div>
  <div id="two"></div>
  <div id="three"></div>
  <div id="four"></div>
  <div id="login"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use css to do this

```
<style type="text/css">
#logo {
    display:none
}
#pink:hover + #logo, #logo:hover {
    display:block;
}
</style>


<div id="pink">pink</div>
<div id="logo">LOGO</div>
```